# Recursive function in C that calculate the result of their multiplication

Tags: c, recursion

I need to write a recursive function with 2 parameters that calculate the result of their multiplication by **only using addition**

exemple :
mult(2,5)=>10

I wrote the function but I think that I'm missing something in the return

```
int mult(unsigned int num1, int num2) {
    if (num1 == 0) return 0;
    return mult(num1 - 1, num2);
}
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/fbdSwf

Comment: distinct lack of addtion here.. also this can only ever return zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return:

```
    return num2 + mult(num1 - 1, num2);
```